# How would I make a save feature that stores the place a user drags multiple panhandlers to and then have a load feature for each save?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-firebase, react-animated

I have a lineup of panhandlers. The user can drag each of these panhandlers wherever they want to on the screen. I want to be able to save where the user leaves the panhandlers to firebase storage. Then, if they want to ever view that save, they can select their save from a drop down list of ones they have made. When they select the one they want, it puts all the panhandlers in the correct position and they can now move the panhandlers again freely.
This is a rough drawing of how it would work.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86z7E.png)

I can save and load from firebase database successfully. To get the right locations, I tried keeping track of the offsets after each move and saving those. Then, when the base view is open, the user chose the view they saved and it adds the offsets to that base view. However, it moves the panhandlers all over the screen.
I also tried keeping track of pan.x._value and pan.y._value for each panhandlers. Then I would set the value of each panhandler to it when the user choose to load. However, that had the same effect with the panhandlers going everywhere.

I have attached an expo link to better exemplify what I have tried. I had to comment out my firebase code as it isn't connected in this snack. Therefore, my code shows how I am saving the locations and the view shows how I am trying to present this with a save button and dropdown list.

https://snack.expo.dev/@jerods/lineupsaving